# TypeScript version mismatch error: TS2304 (TS) Cannot find name 'ExtendableEvent'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022. I created a new React project using React and ASP.NET Core template:

[image]

The code runs fine:

[image]

But I see the following error:

> Error:    TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'ExtendableEvent'.

The error is shown on this file:

[image]

When I check the path, I can see that I have the following versions of TypeScript installed:

[image]

And this is what I have in `packages.json`:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

### Update

I believe the issue here is that the error is raised on file under **TypeScript/4.3** but in my `package.json` the requirement for TypeScript is min: **4.9.5**. However I am not sure how to change the TypeScript version?

My node.js version is 18.17

[image]

Comment: do you have `webworker` in `lib` setting?

Comment: upgrading the nodejs to the latest version could solve the issue in my test, could you pls take a try?

Comment: @Lesiak: I am sorry, I don't follow your question... I am very new to using react

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Can you post your tsconfig.json please?

Comment: @Lesiak: Thanks but I managed to resolved the issue by installing `TypeScript SDK`. Have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by updating Visual Studio 2022 and also Installing TypeScript SDK.

To Install TypeScript SDK:

1. Run Visual Studio 2022 Installer, and click on Modify under Build Tools:
   [image]
2. Choose Individual Components and Make Sure TypeScript SDK is installed.
   [image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126707/typescript-version-mismatch-in-visual-studio-2022/71233978#71233978) helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have a test in my side before and I also faced the error as yours, and I noticed that I didn't use the latest version of nodejs so that I try to update the nodejs by uninstall the old SDK and install the new version, then the issue disappeared. But I didn't remember the old version of my SDK, nor have a screenshot for the same error I met... So I try to reproduce but no luck to reproduce again.

What I can say is, when I start to test with `v15.9.0`, I can create the project through the template successfully, before that, I kept getting exception when creating the project. And I'm sure with `v18.16.1` everything worked.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer... I don't think this is my issue because my node version is already 18.17... I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: thanks for your reply and we might keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I managed to resolve the issue by installing TypeScript SDK (answer below). Not quite sure why the only available option is TypeScript 4.3 SDK (which seems old) but installing it resolved the issue.

Comment: thanks for informing me about it and I voted it : )